# Is there a system call to bind a file descriptor directly into another?

Tags: pipe, file-copy, socket, system-calls, file-descriptors

A read() & write() loop would probably be as good as what I'm looking for, but nevertheless is anything like that around or is it impossible because of an obstacle I didn't envisage ? I'm curious

Comment: Given that it is related to *nix in terms of the system calls, it might be fine here, but it may be better to ask this on StackOverflow. I flagged to bring it to moderator attention; but they may very well see it as being perfectly fine where it is.

Comment: You should explain in better detail what you are trying to do.  Is it to duplicate the descriptor?  Is it to pipe output from one into the other?  Where did the descriptors come from?

Comment: This definitely belongs on stackoverflow. However the answer is `dup2()`.

Comment: sendfile(2) or splice(2) would be more like a "read and write loop"

Comment: I'd say it's perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: I wanted to pipe output from one into the other, thank you goldilocks. I hoped that it would make copying happen entirely in kernel space, and I got my answer. @related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677262/how-can-i-interconnect-two-sockets-in-linux

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbkey's answer is good. If only I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no traditional Unix system call for "copy the full contents of one fd to another". Loops of "read a chunk; stop if EOF; write the chunk" were always written in userspace.

There are some recent additions like sendfile(2) and splice(2) which allow you to do the equivalent of a read-write loop in a single syscall. Using these can improve performance at the expense of portability. (sendfile takes different arguments on different Unices, so you will need some #ifdef)